# PHPMailer: Conditional Statement on Email Template

Tags: php, email, if-statement, phpmailer

Not sure if I am doing this correctly or if it is even possible. Basically, I just need to change the background color of a table `<td>` depending on the value of variable $cascadeType.

The form which accepts user input:

```
<form action="CascadeFunction.php" method="post" name="cascader" id="cascader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label><span class="required">*</span>CASCADE TYPE</label><br /><br />
<label for="Release" class="radioitem">RELEASE
  <input type="radio" name="cascadeType" value="Release" id="CascadeType_1" /></label>
<label for="Update" class="radioitem">UPDATE
  <input type="radio" name="cascadeType" value="Update" id="CascadeType_2" />
</label>
<label for="Reminder" class="radioitem">REMINDER
  <input type="radio" name="cascadeType" value="Reminder" id="CascadeType_3" /></label>
<label for="Information" class="radioitem">INFORMATION
  <input type="radio" name="cascadeType" value="Information" id="CascadeType_4" /></label>
<input class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="POST &amp; CASCADE" />
</form>
```

The submitted data from the above form then gets processed by the file **CascadeFunction.php**. Where its PHPMailer code to send email is:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true); // This tells the PhPMailer that the messages uses HTML.
$mail->MsgHTML(str_replace('%cascadeType%', $CascadeType, file_get_contents('emailtemplates/emailtemplate.php')), dirname(__FILE__));
```

In an attempt to store the variable $cascadeType, I tried using $_SESSIONS as seen on the following code:

```
<?php
// starting the session
 session_start();
 if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
 $_SESSION['cascadeType'] = $_POST['cascadeType'];
 } 
?>
```

Then access the session within the email template (**emailtemplate.php**) using the code:

```
<?php 
 // starting the session
 session_start();
?>
```

Then, within the email template (**emailtemplate.php**), used the conditional statement below.

```
<tr>
    <?php if ($_SESSION['cascadeType'] = "Information") : ?>
    <td style="text-align:center; color:#FFF; background-color:#093; margin:10px; padding:10px 5px;" width="20%">
        <h4 style="font-weight:bold;">%cascadeType%</h4>
    </td>
    <?php elseif ($_SESSION['cascadeType'] = "Update") : ?>
    <td style="text-align:center; color:#FFF; background-color:#09F; margin:10px; padding:10px 5px;" width="20%">
        <h4 style="font-weight:bold;">%cascadeType%</h4>
    </td>
    <?php elseif ($_SESSION['cascadeType'] = "Reminder") : ?>
    <td style="text-align:center; color:#FFF; background-color:#F00; margin:10px; padding:10px 5px;" width="20%">
        <h4 style="font-weight:bold;">%cascadeType%</h4>
    </td>
    <?php else : ?>
    <td style="text-align:center; color:#FFF; background-color:#6C3; margin:10px; padding:10px 5px;" width="20%">
        <h4 style="font-weight:bold;">%cascadeType%</h4>
    </td>
    <?php endif ; ?>
<td style="color:#337AB7; text-align:right; padding-right: 20px;" width="80%">
<h3 style="margin-bottom:2px;">TARGET AUDIENCE</h3>
<p style="margin-top:2px;">%targetAudience%</p>
</td>
```

The email output just displays all table `<td>` and apparently does not work. Please advise on what is the best way to approach the situation if conditional statements will really not work within an email template

Comment: You don't say how you're loading/running this.

Comment: @Synchro, Thanks for viewing. I made changes to my question. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using method `MsgHTML` which seem to expect a plain HTML. But you're giving it some PHP code with conditions. This PHP code is never evaluated, therefore conditions don't work.

You may try to run the template content using `eval` and grab its output, but really you should consider using a templater if you need something a little more than trivial replacement in the templates. Look at Twig templater, for example - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

**Update:**

Re using eval. First of all, I have to say that this may be unsafe, if you're not very careful about what exactly code is executed.

The idea is to read template content (essentially some HTML+PHP code) into a PHP variable, define some other variables that are used in the template and then use PHP function `eval` to run that code.

Something like this:

```
$template = file_get_contents('emailtemplates/emailtemplate.php');
$html = eval('ob_start(); ?>' . $template . '<?php return ob_get_clean();');
```

Or even this

```
ob_start();
require('emailtemplates/emailtemplate.php');
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

Then use the `$html` variable in `MsgHTML`

The important trick in both examples is `ob_*` functions. `ob_start()` starts capturing the output of PHP code and `ob_get_clean()` stops it and returns everything that was returned. Check the documentation on these functions. Also note in example with `eval()` it's important to put `?>` and `<?php` around the template content as unlike `include`, eval starts in PHP context, but not in HTML.

Comment: Thanks @astax. I may use templater in the future but for now, I would like to know how do I go about using `eval` with a conditional statement. Can you shed some light?